# Problem with dummy variables in ML model (python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, data-science

I'm working on a ML model and I have a problem with dummy variables. My data frame hase categorical columns WindGustDir, WindDir3pm and WindDir9am. I need to create dummy variables but the problem is that this three columns have the same data. They are containing wind direction like N, S, W, E, WSW ... so after creating dummy variables I have columns like N, N, N, S, S, S... and I don't know will this make a problem for my model. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Please check out my answer, and if you need more details, adding a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could help us answer your question more precisely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy idea would be to simply add a prefix to your variable, that way you'd have:
`WindGustDir_N`, `WindDir3pm _N` and so on.

It's hard to be more precise without knowing how you actually store your data, but sklearn, one of the most used ML library, [has an encoder to do that](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)